# How to apply word-wrap to ANTD Select title and dropdown items so that it changes the height of the element?

Tags: css, reactjs, antd, css-modules

**I want my ANTD title/selected item to go to the next row and modify the height of the Select.**

I have worked on this example: https://codesandbox.io/s/basic-usage-antd-4-24-7-forked-8jzp29?file=/demo.js

The styles that I am looking to target are:

```css
.ant-select-item-option-content {
  white-space: break-spaces;
  word-break: break-word;
}

.ant-select-show-search.ant-select:not(.ant-select-customize-input)
  .ant-select-selector {
  height: auto;
}
.ant-select-single.ant-select-show-arrow .ant-select-selection-item {
  white-space: normal;
  word-break: break-all;
}
```

**How can I target those when using CSS modules ?**

I have added a class to the dropdown using the ANTD Select API `popupClassName="_dropdown"` which only accepts strings but this is ignored when using CSS modules.

Answer (score 0):

I have achieved the wrapping of content in this way.

```
.ant-select-item-option-content {
  white-space: wrap  !important
}
```